# How can I store images in mongodb with node.js?

Tags: javascript, binary, mongodb, node.js

I'm using the current application stack:

node.js,
mongodb,
express (for node.js), and
mongoose (for node.js ... gives me orm capabilities)

I'm getting used to everything and have the regular CRUD stuff working.  However, I can't figure out how to store binary/gridfs/BSON stuff in mongo and retrieve it.

Can someone give me an example using node.js/mongo/mongoose or know of a good one or know if its possible?

Comment: Looks like mongoose depends on node-mongodb-native which can store binary data files I guess according to its github: https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native     Seems like mongoose just needs some good wrapper functionality for files to access this?

Comment: I think thats probably what I'll do since I'm using amazon ec2 ... ill probably just store them in s3 and store their locations in the database

Comment: I'm now significantly happier and using another one of TJ's libraries for node: https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox ... for storing them to s3 ... way better than putting them into mongo

Answer (score 2):

According to Guillermo Rauch from the mongoose project, adding support to GridFS is not their priority right now (http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm/browse_thread/thread/1bce50d90680d502)

Mentioned this here, so that somebody interested may pickup the task and hack GridFS support into mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/examples/types.js#L30 lists down how you can add BSON Binary type using the node-mongodb-native.

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest to get the RESTfulness out-of-the-box !!

Comment: How do you retrieve the binary value.  I'm converting a python app that does this with ease and no hassle, but in Node.JS it's not working.  It says it's of type 2 if you just send the records that come out of the driver to the client.  If you console.log them you get binary data.  I don't see many examples in the tests that have how to do it.