# How to upload an image to node/mongodb backend from ios swift

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image from the iphone gallery onto a backend that is constructed using node and mongodb as the db. I am essentially very new to app development and have had 0 luck in finding any useful information. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some information about storing images with node.js in a mongodb.
[Uploading and storing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192452/uploading-and-storing-images)

And uploading an image with swift:
[Uploading file with parameters using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire/27014372#27014372)